# A property of a custom type in the property window (MS Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Some staff
}

public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyClass MyObj { get; set; }
}
```

I want MyObj property to be able to set through the property window of MS Visual Studio. However it is grayed like a readonly property.

I suppose that I should add some designer attributes, but have no idea where and which.

**Edit**

The simplest solution is to inherit **MyClass** from **Component**. No attributes are required.

```
public class MyClass : Component
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if this works

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    // Some staff
}


public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]     
    public MyClass MyObj { get; set; }
}
```

**EDITED after user comment:**
This test code works as expected to me:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyObj = new MyClass();

    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]     
    public MyClass MyObj { get; set; }
}


[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

**EDITED AGAIN:**
If you want property editor to behave like you describe, the simplest solution I can give you is this

```
public class MyClass : Control // if it must be visible on form
```

or

```
public class MyClass : Component // if it must be just a component
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. It doesn't look like readonly any more, but I still cannot set a value to the property. I expect a drop down list of available objects of MyClass type expanding when clicking on the property. There are nothing there, even (none). Any ideas?

Comment: @Zenya: when instantiating control, do you use `MyObj = new MyClass();`?

Comment: Just tried your example, but it doesn't allow to edit (set a new value) to the property. To understand what I mean, would you like to try the following: 1) change "class MyClass" to "class MyClass : System.Windows.Forms.Panel" and 2) delete all two attributes from your example. And you will see what behavior I desire (a drop down selector appears in the property field).

Comment: @Zenya: sorry, I don't understand which are your needs :( If I do what you ask I have a dropdown in which I can select one `MyClass` object from the ones in your form. If you place one or more `MyClass` objects on your form and open `MyControl.MyObj` combobox, you'll see all of them...

Comment: That's great that you could see a dropdown! That what I wanted to show you. The dropdown appeared because we inherited MyClass from System.Windows.Forms.Panel. Now I would like to have the same behavior for the initial example, without adding "System.Windows.Forms.Panel". Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @Zenya: ok, I figured out what you need. I provided an easy solution, but I'm not sure it is the correct one or the best.

Comment: Now it behave as I desire. I wrongly thought that this could be done only by setting attributes... Anyway, thank you.